# Sharepoint webpart- edit mode Display

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have developed a custom webpart which is being displayed correctly and has some external parameters and being supplied when it is used in the page.

There is a problem in displaying that webpart in edit mode. In edit mode it is not visible as the page footer comes up and only little portion of the webpart is being displayed. To see the whole webpart I need to scroll through. This problem is happening only when the web part is in edit mode.

In Display mode it is Fantastic.

The Way it looks on the Page in Edit Mode is:

[image]

Could anyone point me whats being missed and why it is happening?

Thank You

Hari Gillala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. If you have edited the master page/page layout, you might not have closed a html tag, or the styling might be wrong.
2. With the custom toolpart, is it outputting valid html?, check that you have built the table correctly, and are using the correct styles.

Comment: Like you said It was the table tag which was not closed properly and made this issue. Thank you.